# SQL Server: Convert a month name (string) to a date

Tags: sql-server, datetime, types, type-conversion

I have a table with a month name in it as type varchar. e.g. "November". Can I convert this to a date field?

```
CONVERT(DATETIME,main.ReportMonth) AS ReportMonthDate
CAST(main.ReportMonth AS DATETIME) AS ReportMonthDate
```

both result in a conversion failure.

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Well the string "November" is NOT a valid date by itself. It needs a date and year as well which you could easily add.

Comment: You are right it's not a date. But I want to turn it into one so I can do date query/sorting stuff with it. i.e. if current month = November then....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hard code a string value at the end of your input value. Something like this.

```
declare @ReportMonth varchar(10) = 'November'

select cast(@ReportMonth + ' 1, 2015' as date)
```

Or if you want to make the year portion be dynamic based on the current date you could modify that slightly like this.

```
select cast(@ReportMonth + ' 1, ' + cast(datepart(year, getdate()) as char(4)) as date)
```